# .htaccess rewrite: redirect all URLs except home URL and assets

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I would like all URLs except my root URL (`/` and `/index.php`) and the JS/CSS and image assets it uses, to redirect to another URL. All assets are contained in the /assets directory

Here's what I have so far but it's not working

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(?!js|css)([^.]*)$ $1\.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.assets$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/style.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$

RewriteRule $ http://berlincallingny.eventbrite.com [R=302,L]
```

The rules I need are:

- do not rewrite any URL containing "assets"
- Do not rewrite index.php
- Do not rewrite style.php
- Do not rewrite the root URL
- do not rewrite any URL containing .css or .js

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that it's not redirecting? Or is it redirecting when it shouldn't?

Comment: Yes a more descriptive information of what happens would help here.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex for `assets` directory is not correct here:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.assets$
```

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets(/.*|)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(index|style)\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ / [R=302,L]
```